# Finding remainder of a Maclaurin Series

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

So I was given the following prompt:

"The function $f$  has derivatives of all orders for all real numbers and $f^4(x)=e^{2x-1}$. If the $3$rd degree Taylor polynomial for $f$ about $x = 0$ is used to approximate $f$ on the interval $[0, 2]$, what is the Lagrange error bound for the maximum error on the interval $[0, 2]$?"

I know that the error bound formula looks something like the following: $R_3(x)\leq|\frac{f(z)}{4!}(x)^4|$ for approximating the error of a third degree Maclaurin series, and I also understand that once I found the $z$ value of the equation I'd just have to plug in $2$ to get my answer, but I'm confused about how I'd go about finding the $f(z)$ value. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First, it is better to use $f^{(4)}$ to denote the $4$th derivative. $f^4$ looks like the $4$th power of $f$. Second, the correct form of the remainder is $$
\frac{{f^{(4)} (z)}}{{4!}}x^4 
$$ where $z$ lies between $0$ and $x$. Can you proceed from here? Note that the question does not ask you to determine $f$ at any points just to give an estimate for the remainder that holds for all $0 \leq x\leq 2$. For that, you do not need to know the value of $z$ for any particular $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right formula is $\left|\frac{f^{(4)}(z)}{4!} x^4\right|$ where $z$ lies between $0$ and $x$.  You are given that the interval of interest is $[0,2]$.

We just need an upper bound on it. Notice that $f^{(4)}$ and $x^4$ are both nonnegative increasing function, hence you just need to evaluate their value at $2$ to find an upperbound.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I'm coming up with about 13.39, does that look right to you?

Comment: yes, I get the same value.